# Why does hash template specialization require result_type and argument_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

Why does C++11 require a hash template specialization to define `result_type` and `argument_type`?  I found some old code where a user-defined type is successfully used for an `unordered_map<>` key but doesn't have these two `typedef`'s.

```
namespace std {
  template<> struct hash<MyNamespace::Foo> {
    typedef size_t result_type;
    typedef MyNamespace::Foo argument_type;
    size_t operator() (const MyNamespace::Foo& f ) const { return (size_t) f.u32InternalValue; }
  };
}
```

Comment: @cigien e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash has Member Types (until C++20)

Comment: Just because an implementation of `std::unordered_map` doesn't (use to) break if you provide it with a non-conforming hash doesn't mean the requirement for `std::hash` wasn't there.

Comment: It might be worth asking why c++ *no longer* requires this from c++20. I think it's still the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the old way of specifying function object traits, unrelated to supplying the [Hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash) to an unordered container.

In C++11 it's still somewhat of a pain to synthesize them from an expression. By C++17 it's relatively easy to do, and they are deprecated members, and in C++20 that requirement is lifted.

Comment: so after C++20 what is the correct way of declaring type of you variable then? Previously I could write: `std::hash<std::string>::result_type`

Comment: @Gelldur it's always `size_t`